# Can I have tables in 3NF form while also having many attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, normalization

I am trying to find a good example for 3 tables that have a relation and in 3NF form. All examples I see have only like 2-3 attributes in their tables.

Can I have a 3NF form with all 3 tables having like 5-6 attributes each? Or is it that usually when you break it up to 3NF, the attributes gets reduced to commonly 2-3?

For example, I commonly see like:

```
**Student Table**
Student ID
Student Name
Course ID

**Course Table**
Course ID
Course Name

**Lecturer Table**
Lecturer ID
Lecturer Name
Course ID
```

I am looking for tables examples which maintain 3NF and holds 5-6 attributes. Tnks.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.diranieh.com/Database/Figures/Schema3NF.gif)

Comment: 3NF has nothing to do with the number of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a car database - there are really a lot of attributes possible:

- id
- type [combi, limousine, coupe]
- number of doors
- length
- width
- height
- wheelbase
- empty weight
- maximum weight
- turn radius
- boot (trunc) volume
- ...

A second table could contain different motor types
- id
- type [diesel, otto]
- cylinder capacity
- compression
- turbo [yes/no]
- [and many, many, many specific motor details]

A third table could link together all available vehicle and motor combinations:
- vehicleId
- motorId
(key would be both rows then)

Further tables could contain information about other exchangable vehicle components (gear drive, brake system, heating, air-conditioning, ...).

Just imagine a sufficiently complex materia and you find other examples. What about different services offered by cities - your columns would be of boolean values then (at least if you don't have any detailed descriptions stored in your database you'd be linking to the cities via a reference table).

Details about countries - what do you think the database of the [CIA's world fact book](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/) looks like?

Or the database of a clinical information system?

A database containing facts for stars and other astronomical objects.

[to be continued...]